Integration of an Equation that I'm unable to solve
There's this equation I'm unable to integrate, and I'm good at integration, but only the ones which are not very complex because I've just started learning integration this year. I need help to find out what is the answer to this:
Q. $\int_{0}^{t}\frac{u}{uax+2}dx$ ($u$, $a$ are constants).
The answer should be from the following:

$\frac{at+2}u$

$\frac1{ua}\ln\left(\frac{uat+2}2\right)$

$\frac1a\ln (uat+2)$

$\frac1a\ln\left(\frac{uat+2}2\right)$



Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

$\int_{0}^{x} \frac{u}{uat+2}dt=\frac{u}{ua}\int_{0}^{x} \frac{1}{uat+2}d(uat+2)=\frac{1}{a}\left(\ln (uax+2)-\ln 2 \right)=\frac{\ln \frac{uax+2}{2}}{a}$

This question doesn’t meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it (which encourages low-quality questions), why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the meta announcement regarding quality standards.

@AnneBauval Ok, I will read it soon.

@Morten, your answer is correct, but I need an explanation of each step to understand since this is a complex question for me.

@Moon_Hawk77 tell me which step you do not understand

Actually every step is somewhat hard for me to catch what's getting solved, could you explain every step, for what you are solving? I'm sorry for the trouble, I'm really new to this.

@Moon_Hawk77 Actually, you need to add some of your thinking or ideas to make the question look ok, not like I am helping you with your homework.

I..don't get what you mean..you want me to try to understand your answer or check if I've written the question correctly?

@Moon_Hawk77 Just add more information to your question like what you have tried, otherwise, it does not meet the standard for this site. You can see you have a downvote for this question.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

As commented yesterday with more detail,  this answer is wrong when $uax+2\le0$.
